# Post show up as post and pages

Tags: errors

I am having a weird issue lately, in the WP Admin panel, all my Post show up under Post and under Pages, they all link to the same article.  If I create a new Post it shows up under Pages as well. I am running the newest stable version of WP, I have tried all my themes even the twentyten and twentyeleven themse, it still happens.  I have never had anything like this happen, any ideas?

---

**UPDATE**

Ok I have no idea what the actual cause is but I did install a fresh version of WP and then made a post and it worked as normal, only showed up under post and not under pages.  I then installed the theme I am working on and made a post, it showed up under post and pages so it has to be an issue somewhere in my theme...pretty weird issue though, because even with my theme not in use, it still makes it happen just by being there

Comment: are you using / have you tried resetting permalinks?

Comment: check your theme's function.php also look for any plugins that may be doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wanted to post the solution here instead of deleting just in case this ever helps anyone else.

The problem was this 1 small function I had tucked away in a setting file...

```
/**
 * change number of posts shown per page in admin area
 */
function admin_pagination(){
    global $wp_query;
    $per_page = 5;
    $wp_query->query('showposts='. $per_page);
}
add_action('admin_head', 'admin_pagination');
```

This caused all `Post` to show up under the Admin section for `Post` and `Pages` so do not use it!  I had found this snippet on a WP site somewhere